# Page.EnableEventValidation = false does not recognize new dropdownlist values

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

My test webform has 1 `dropdownlist` and 2 `buttons`. This is it:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTest" runat="server" >
        <asp:ListItem>Value 0</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Value 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Value 2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="ButtonClient" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="ChangeDropDown(); return false;" />

<asp:Button ID="ButtonServer" runat="server" Text="Server" onclick="ButtonServer_Click" />
</form>
```

This is the `javascript` function `ChangeDropDown()`:

```
function ChangeDropDown() {
        for (i = document.getElementById("<%=DropDownListTest.ClientID%>").options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            document.getElementById("<%=DropDownListTest.ClientID%>").remove(i);
        }
        var opt = document.createElement("option");

        opt.text = "Complete";
        opt.value = "Complete";
        document.getElementById("<%=DropDownListTest.ClientID%>").options.add(opt);


        var opt2 = document.createElement("option");
        opt2.text = "Not Complete";
        opt2.value = "Not Complete";
        document.getElementById("<%=DropDownListTest.ClientID%>").options.add(opt2);
}
```

And this is the codebehind:

```
    protected void ButtonServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string val = this.DropDownListTest.SelectedValue;
    }
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.EnableEventValidation = false;
        //"Invalid postback or callback argument" if I remove this.
    }
```

Let's say that I click on `button ButtonClient` (which changes the values of dropdown), select "Complete" and then click on `ButtonServer`. In codebehind, the value of `this.DropDownListTest.SelectedValue` equals "Value 0" instead of "Complete".

I understand why I'm getting the problem, but is there another solution besides adding the items codebehind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the value in the standard way as the server is not aware that the items have been changed for the drop down.

However, you can get the value directly from the request:

```
protected void ButtonServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string val = Request[this.DropDownListTest.UniqueID];
}
```

Comment: In my case it works well since `Value` and `Text` are the same. But what would I use if I wanted to retrieve the `Text` instead of `Value`? Thanks.

Comment: The `Text` is not posted back to the server. If you need the text, you can either: (1) rebuild the items on the server to match the change made on the client or (2) use hidden fields to store the text from the javascript and get the value for these hidden fields on the server.